# TFS Extension Data Service C#

Tags: c#, tfs

Does the TFS Extension Data web service have a similar service in C#? I am trying to get custom TFS extension data through C# instead of REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use C# instead of JavaScript, as REST API (httprequest) can be called in any language.

There are two ways to interact with the data storage service: REST APIs or a Microsoft-provided client service available as part of the VSS SDK. Please check the rest api in the following link, and call this api in your code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage#advanced

The getValue method is a wrapper around the REST APIs, issuing a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
GET _apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extensionName}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents/myKey
```

Comment: Would this work for data that is general to tfs? For example we have data we added that is apart of the iteration and its not scoped to a specific user.

Comment: Settings and document collections can be scoped to either Project Collection or User, could you elaborate how do you want to use iteration data?

Comment: Thanks! Found the specific call using wireshark.